VSCode no "Add missing properties" menu for TS intersection types
When I extend the interface type, I can get "Add missing properties"

However, when I use intersection types, I don't get "Add missing properties".

What did I do wrong?
Thanks！
Version information
Typescript: 5.4.5
Vscode: 1.89.1
When using intersection types, vscode will have "Add missing properties".
